# access object paratamters node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, response, stringify

I am logging a `response` that I get from the server after sending a post request, and it looks like this:

```
{"output":"basic question #1. how do I calculate the area of a rectangle based on users input in python?"}
```

now i want to access `output` as type plain text (string). I tried this:

```
 console.log(body)
     //this returns  {"output":"basic question #1. how do I calculate the area of a rectangle based on users input in python?"}
 console.log(JSON.stringify(body))
    //this returns "{\"output\":\"calculate the area of a rectangle based on users input in python\"}"
```

how would I access `output` within the `body` response?

Comment: Sounds like you want `JSON.parse` not `JSON.stringify`. Unless it's already parsed in which case `body.output` will do the trick.

Comment: @Andy that worked indeed. thank you v much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in method called `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript that will convert JSON to a JavaScript object.

---

Follow these steps to get the result you want!

1. **Skip if already parsed!** First, you need to use `JSON.parse()` to parse the `string` JSON into a valid JavaScript object. As a parameter, you pass in the string that you want to parse.

   ```js
   JSON.parse(body);
   ```
2. To access the body, you can either use dot notation or bracket notation. Either one will work; you use them like below.

   ```js
   // Dot notation
   body.output;

   // Bracket notation
   body["output"];
   ```

The final code should look like this.

```js
const body = `{"output": "Calculate the area of a rectangle based on users input in Python."}`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(body);

// Dot notation
console.log(parsed.output);

// Bracket notation
console.log(parsed["output"]);
```

---

In conclusion, the `JSON.parse()` method built-into JavaScript should help solve the issue.